# how to use a jCheckBox to execute one query if selected and another if not

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

I want to display some students fees track on a JFrame when a jbutton is clicked after typing the StudentID in a jTextField.

The student data is stored in MySQL Db, the table studentrolls contains info about the students with STRollID as Primary Key and StudentID, BachID as Foreign Key and the table fees contain all students fee record of *past years* and *actual year* with STRollID as Primary Key and BachID as Foreign Key.

I want to display after inserting the StudentID on a jTextField and clicking a jButton only *actual year* fee if a jCheckBoxonlythisyearfee is selected, otherwise, the frame will display all the fee record on a jTable and on some jLabels.

I wrote this code, I am not getting any error but when I run the file, I'm getting all the student fee records but when I'm clicking on the jCheckBoxonlythisyearfee nothing is happening am not getting only this year fee record.
Is there anything wrong with my code? Please help.

```
private void rSButtonIconDsearchstidActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        Date d = new Date();
        int year = d.getYear();
        int currentYear = year + 1900;
        boolean thisyrchecboxisSelected = jCheckBoxonlythisyearfee.isSelected();
        String sqlquerystfeeslist;
        if (thisyrchecboxisSelected) {

            sqlquerystfeeslist = "SELECT * FROM studentrolls, fees WHERE studentrolls.StudentID = ? AND studentrolls.STRollID = fees.STRollID AND studentrolls.BachID = '"
                    + currentYear + "' ORDER BY studentrolls.BachID";
        } else {

            sqlquerystfeeslist = "SELECT * FROM studentrolls, fees WHERE studentrolls.StudentID = ? AND studentrolls.STRollID = fees.STRollID ORDER BY studentrolls.BachID";

        }

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqlquerystfeeslist);
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sqlquerystfeeslist);

        if (!jTextFieldsearchstid.getText().isEmpty()) {

            preparedStatement.setString(1, jTextFieldsearchstid.getText());
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            DefaultTableModel tblModelfee = (DefaultTableModel) jTablestfeeslist.getModel();
            tblModelfee.setRowCount(0);    // to clear the table before inserting new data

            while (resultSet.next()) {

                int stfeebalenceint;
                int feecostint = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("MontantFrais"));
                int paidamountint = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("MontantPayE"));
                stfeebalenceint = feecostint - paidamountint;

                String feestatus;
                if (stfeebalenceint <= 0) {
                    feestatus = "SOLDE";
                } else {
                    feestatus = "NO SOLDE";
                }

                String scolaryearfee = resultSet.getString("BachID");
                String feetype = resultSet.getString("TypeFrais");
                String feecost = String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("MontantFrais"));
                String paidamount = String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("MontantPayE"));
                String stfeebalence = String.valueOf(stfeebalenceint);

                String stfeeslistTableData[] = {scolaryearfee, feetype, feecost, paidamount, stfeebalence, feestatus};
                tblModelfee.addRow(stfeeslistTableData);

                int stTotfeecost = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < jTablestfeeslist.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    stTotfeecost = stTotfeecost + Integer.parseInt(jTablestfeeslist.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                }

                int stTotpaidamount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < jTablestfeeslist.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    stTotpaidamount = stTotpaidamount + Integer.parseInt(jTablestfeeslist.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
                }

                int stTotfeebalence;
                stTotfeebalence = stTotfeecost - stTotpaidamount;

                String stTotfeestatus;
                if (stTotfeebalence <= 0) {
                    stTotfeestatus = "SOLVABLE";
                } else {
                    stTotfeestatus = "INSOLVABLE";
                }

                jLabelstTotfeecost.setText(Integer.toString(stTotfeecost));
                jLabelstTotpaidamount.setText(Integer.toString(stTotpaidamount));
                jLabelstTotfeebalence.setText(Integer.toString(stTotfeebalence));
                jLabelstTotfeestatus.setText(stTotfeestatus);
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Veillez taper le matricule d'un eleve svp.");
        }

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "erreur des donnees: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end, "nothing is happening am not getting only this year fee record". What do you mean? Maybe, "I'm **getting** only this year's fee record"?

Comment: @HoRn, Actually what I need is that If I click the jcheckbox the table should display only current year record else it would display all the record. But when I run the app and click the jcheckbox nothing is happening. I don't know if I used well the IF Statement with the two queries.

Comment: 1. Have you tried logging on `if (thisyrchecboxisSelected) {` cases? Add a log line on both cases. This will show you if the problem is with the interface.  2. If the interface works fine, check that the query is workable. Try it.

Comment: @ HoRn, you know it's working actually, there is nothing wrong with my code but the thing is when I click the jcheckbox I will have to click again the search button to display the result of the current(actual) year.   And if I deselect again the checkbox I'll have to click again the search button to get the other result(I mean all the records) . Now am wondering if there is a way to get the same result without clicking the search button twice.